# Does Apache Ignite supports serialized Avro objects?

Tags: avro, ignite, gridgain

I have Avro objects that would like to serialize and store in Apache Ignite (or Grid Gain).

Is that data format supported by Apache Ignite? 
Goal is to extract specific fields from Avro based on dynamic request if that data type is supported.. If not - what would be workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ignite use it's own binary format:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller

it's allow to read only specific fields too. So SQL request will read only particular fields that you requested. For this you need to convert you avro object to binary object, see javadoc of org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObject and org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectBuilder for details.

Comment: Does this means that Avro needs to be converted first to that Ignite Binary object? (so Avro can not be just serialized and stored in cache?). If yes - how to convert Avro to that Binary object? Write specific class to do that? Does example of that class exist already? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Joe, there's no facilities for this, you need manually read filed from avro and put them to binary object. I believe this can be automated, but right now there's no facilities for this. you are welcome to contribute you converters to apache ignite project .

Comment: So steps are currently: 1) Someone (or some system) sends Avro binary-encoded message, 
2) I create a Java class to read that Binary Avro and convert it into some Java Object (decode original avro binary), 3) Store that NEW Java Object into Apache Ignite cache (and cache can be set to be Binary), 4) Read from Cache.  Correct? (if yes - that means I will always need to create a Java class in order to read original Avro and then store data to Ignite?)

Comment: you can read field directly from avro object and write them to binary builder and then build binary object that will be saved on memory, without intermediate java object it will be faster. Also this means that you don't need pre-existent java class and this can even work if schema isn't well defined.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a simple example of that process? (e.g. from JSON or from AVRO to cache using Binary Builder?)

Comment: Checkout ignite tests: org/apache/ignite/internal/binary/BinaryObjectBuilderDefaultMappersSelfTest.java . There you can find how to use binary object builder, avro is even simple: 
        ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = readerBuilder.withConf(config)
            .build();
GenericRecord nextRecord = reader.read();
nextRecord.get("field1"));

read filed from avro and put them to binary object builder, when you read/write all fields from avro, just call build() method of binary object builder and get BinaryObject which then you should save to cache.

Comment: Thanks. Conceptually it make sense.. I am new-ish to java and Ignite.. Do you have a full example of that ParquetReader... ? And also what is the full URL for a first example (org/apache/ignite/internal/binary/BinaryObjectBuilderDefault‌​MappersSelfTest.java)? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Joe, the first link was from ignite tests in git, let me prepare an example for this and share with you today/tomorrow.

Comment: please find a small example here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxVTrBEDRMr2MW9fM1JYWGNTYkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the effort Michael. I was able to see the code in the Main (Test.java). Please correct me if I am wrong but it seems that builder.setField("s1", rec.get("s1"));' assumes that I know ahead of time that field S1 and S2 exist in Avro. The problem is that Users can send any format of Avro (e.g. maybe there is no S1 nor S2 but some F1 to F50 and next Avro maybe G1, G2 and G3 only). So I can not rely on knowing the schema ahead of time (S1 and S2 in example). How to build it dynamically? (accommodating any schema that comes with either 3 or 50 fields and then dinamically build Cache)..

Comment: that's right, but avro format requires some predefined schema, so you need user to send you a schema too, you can get list of fields form this schema: schema.getFields()

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for clarification. Schema is always sent with Avro so it can be used to dynamically get fields (schema.getFields()) and we can use that information to build the cache... One question regarding JSON-like structure - is it possible to use NESTED JSON schema in Ignite Cache? (so instead of 1-dimensional schema of Key->Value pairs in JSON - to be instead a Key that has another level Keys which have 3-rd level keys which then has values). How would Ignite maintain multi-level relationship? (I have seen only 1-level examples so far for Objects stored in Ignite)... Thanks.